# Linux History Expansion escaping colon which is not mean as a modifier (in zsh)

Tags: command-line, zsh, history-expansion

I have a command like:

```
echo test
```

Now i want to use the last parameter inside another command with history extension inside a zsh. My other command have a leading colon ":" in it, so I want a result of:

```
echo test:someothertext
```

And I try it with linux bash history extension like the following:

```
echo !!$:someothertext
```

The :s will be interpret as a modifier and the result is:

```
echo testsomeothertext
```

So, the needed colon is missing.

Real scenario is more useful and uses git commands (git show branch:file), but this echo example is easier to reproduce on each system.

I already have tried to use "\" as an escaping for the colon which don't work ("\" is printed in the result too)
And I have tried to use a valid modifier so that the second colon would not be interpret but it also don't work.

So I tried this:

```
echo !!$:p:someothertext
```

which results in:

```
zsh: substitution failed
```

Comment: The tag says "bash" but the error message "zsh".

Comment: hi @HaukeLaging, yes you are right. I adjusted it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not really nice but in `bash` this works:

```
echo !!$\
:someothertext
```

Comment: hmmm i would like to put it in as a one liner maybe with other parameters expansions in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use:

```
echo !!$':moretext'
```

Or:

```
echo !!$'':moretext
```

Or:

```
echo $_:moretext
```

Comment: hmmm i don't want the apostrophe in the executed command. for echo it may work but in my more complex use case of "git show branch:file" (where i will replace the branch name) the apostrophe is a problem.

the echo $_ works on echo. But if i use f.e. the following command as the second command `git show $_:filename` i get `fatal: Invalid object name 'test'.`